# Android run Gradle task after app install

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

need help with Gradle tasks. I need to run some "taskX" after an app was installed (after "installDebug" task). I've also tried to make the task like this:

```
task taskX(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebug') {
     commandLine 'sh', './myScript.sh'
}
```

but it didn't execute. 
I actually can do this by Android Studio build configuration, but I also want to do this by Gradle wrapper.

Comment: you are not using the correct task dependency type:  `taskX.dependsOn installDebug` means "if I execute task *taskX* then task *installDebug* must be executed first. you need to use finalizer task dependency type ( see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks ), e.g.: `installDebug.finalizedBy taskX`

Comment: @Warble how would you run a command after installation through build config?